# Create matrix of object

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Hi I have to create a matrix of object with certain dimension.is it possible.the dimension of the matrix are int while the content are object.How can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something like

```
myobjectMatrix foo[][] = new myobjectMatrix[width][height]

// Remember that everything in the matrix is initialized to null so
// you must initialize everything
foo[0][0] = new myobjectMatrix();
```

Answer (score 5):

A little search does not harm. It's really simple.

```
Object[][] matrix = new Object[rows][cols];
```